# How to Create pop up screen on windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

I'm very new to creating Windows Mobile applications. I have a Submit button on a form and at the button click I want to open a small popup that overlaps the current window with checkbox and button. After clicking the button on pop up form will submit.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "pop up" screen by creating a new Form class as normal but manually set the size and location so that it doesn't occupy the entire screen. From the calling screen, use the .ShowDialog() function to display your "pop up" form. Note that if your application is maximized to hide the windows title bar, this popup form will display the title bar again, as it doesn't occupy the entire screen.

Comment: AFAIK all custom dialogs (forms) on windows mobile will be maximized. To be able to use a sized dialog (form) one has to start the project based on WindowsCE SDK and not WindowsMobile.But you can resize the form (dialog) after creating it using the native API SetWindowLong().

Comment: @josef Manually setting the size & location of a Form class works fine in a windows mobile project. Try it :)

Answer (score 0):

If it can help anybody, at least me, the location property couldn't be changed just because of the formborderStyle property. Set it to none, and you'll be able to change the location of your form !